# quick sort algorithm, solving recurrence relation

Tags: quicksort

[image: can anyone solve the question in the image and explain the answer!]
Please solve the question in the image and tell me how to find the order of growth in a recurrence relation.

Comment: This screenshot is unreadable for me.

Comment: What is the order of growth of the solution to the quicksort-like recurrence, F(n) = 2N +1 +1/N(sigma k>=1 to k<=N) {F(k-1)+F(N-k) with F0=0?                                        options: 0,1,1/N,N,NLogN,N^2,N^3...